# Can we can the "Many Memes of Meta" question

Tags: support, meta, off-topic

The question [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) stopped being funny at least a year ago and has been updated no less than 8 times this year just to change Welbog's name.

Can someone please take it out the back and shoot it or at least archive it / protect it to stop people bumping it to the front page every two weeks just because someone found it again and thought it would be hilarious comedy pesto to update it with the latest details.

I normally hate 'stick-in-the-mud' type meta requests but this post gets way more attention than it deserves.

Comment: In support of my argument please consider there are people like myself who participate in many SE betas and regularly check meta to stay and keep others up to date. What value does this question provide to the network being bumped to the front page every two weeks?

Comment: If "take it out back and shoot it" means lock it, then I'm for it. SO's definition of what constitutes a "meme" is comical

Comment: [Why, thank you, @Michael](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21224#21224) Also, the "Related" sidebar has never been more related.

Comment: I'm sure Welbog was [on a boat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487) at least _once_ when he changed his name, which makes that list of critical importance.

Comment: I down-voted instead of posting an answer. That's a MetaSO meme, too, right?

Comment: OMG WHY ARE YOU DOWNVOTING ME??? <-- meme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that the constant updating every time Welbog changes his name is excessive. However, I don't think we should remove the post entirely. Although a lot of it is silly, it does provide some historical context to things which are mentioned frequently on Meta. More than once I've wondered what the heck someone was talking about, and found the post useful for explaining these things. Call it silly, but it serves a purpose.

I do think that it would be reasonable to lock the answers which generate repeated, unnecessary blather. The welbog post you pointed out is an excellent example - locking just that answer would reduce the unnecessary bumps, but still keep the thread around for historical significance. Or, the whole thing could be locked, but that would prevent any new memes from ever being explained.

Comment: Trivia: Welbog has had a *lot* more names than appear in that list... That particular answer has been locked before, during which time the updates stopped. When Wave dies, all those names will be lost in time, like tears in the rain... Point being, the efforts of OCD individuals currently updating the list are already in vain.

Comment: The thing about in-jokes is they stop being funny once everyone is in. If you sort the answers by active you will notice that most of those jokes: freehand circles, jquery, plural are all so old, none of the regulars here even joke about them anymore. If you want to be part of the crowd then regularly hang around meta and answer questions. Looking at that post may make you understand what the in crowd is (was) joking about, but its not going to make you a better user. That Q is +1000 sentimental votes and -1000 in usefulness.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a non-issue.

There is no difference between  whiny "why was I downvoted" or "I can't post questions anymore" questions, or generally *crappy posts,* and this one - they all are a waste of your time, and appear on the front page frequently. Only with the Memes question, *you already know you're not interested* and can move on.

Comment: Well, there is one difference -- we do close the "why was I downvoted"/"I can't post questions anymore" posts. Rapidly

Comment: @Michael sure. But they still turn up all the time. I don't see the point in complaining about one specific post - you can simply ignore it. If it were 20 or 30, okay, but not for just one

Comment: @Pekka - If it is a non-issue would it be a problem if I created a "Many Names of Welbog" question and it were updated every two weeks or so? One bad post leads to another.

Comment: @xiaohouzi that question is now over 2 years old and has been viewed 15,000 times. It hasn't spawned other questions of that kind during that time, has it? As said - if there were 30 posts like this, I would agree with you. But I think we should leave that one well alone.

Comment: @Pekka - It doesn't need to spawn new questions or answers because the same old ones keep rearing their ugly heads. It's no different if the answers keep being updated or new ones created. It has the same effect and same level of disruption.